# Given a list, can can I use dictionary comprehension to represent list items as keys and how many times they show up in the list as values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary-comprehension

Essentially I'm writing a function that receives a list as input and returns a dictionary that counts how many times the data in the list is repeated.

```
#Example:
count_occurrences(["a", "b", "c", "a", "a," "b"])

#output: 
{"a" : 3, "b" : 2, "c": 1}
```

My solution so far has been:

```
def count_occurrences(a_list):
    count_list = {}
    for i in a_list:
        if i not in count_list:
            count_list[i] = 1
        else: 
            count_list[i] += 1 
    return count_list
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to use Dictionary Comprehension to shorten/optimize this script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5829377/7832176

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in class made specifically for this. It's called a Counter and it already implements a dict to you don't need to convert it.

```
from collections import Counter

print(Counter(["a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b"]))

#Output
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})
```